# Adding subtrees with xml attributes to a boost property tree

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I'm using `boost::ptree` for creating an xml file

```
ptree tree;
ptree & subtree = tree.add("sometag", "");
ptree & subsubtree = tree.add("someothertag", "");
...
write_xml(stfilename, declarationTree, std::locale(),
          xml_writer_settings<std::string>(' ', 4));
```

This creates following XML file

```
<sometag>
   <someothertag>
   ...
   </someothertag>
</sometag>
```

So far so good, but I need to put xml attributes into the `<sometag>` tag.

Instead of this:

```
<sometag>
  ...
```

I want this:

```
<sometag someattribute="somevalue">
  ...
```

How can attributes be specified? The boost documentation is very unclear about this.

Comment: Your samples don't add up.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<xmlattr>` special child node namespace:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::property_tree::ptree tree;
    tree.put("sometag.someothertag.<xmlattr>.someattribute", "somevalue");

    write_xml(std::cout, tree,
            boost::property_tree::xml_writer_settings<std::string>(' ', 4));
}
```

Prints

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sometag>
    <someothertag someattribute="somevalue"/>
</sometag>
```